# Linker command failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

While attempting to compile and run my project, I ran into the error above. Here is a more detailed look:

```
duplicate symbol _timeTick in:
/Users/zstephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStore_2-ejjgywkgxdulkogcohzbzojgqpzp/Build/Intermediates/MyStore 2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStore.build/Objects-normal/i386/TimeController.o
/Users/zstephen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStore_2-ejjgywkgxdulkogcohzbzojgqpzp/Build/Intermediates/MyStore 2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStore.build/Objects-normal/i386/DeviceDetailViewController.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How do I fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Here is the 3 files timeTick is used:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int timeTick = 0;

@interface TimeController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UILabel *labelTime;
}
- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender;


@end
```

.m:

```
@implementation TimeController


NSTimer *timer;   

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    labelTime.text = @"0";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    - (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:(self) selector:             (@selector(tick)) userInfo:(nil) repeats:(YES)];
}

-(void)tick{
    timeTick++;
    NSString *timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
    labelTime.text = timeString;



}


@end
```

Finally, there is a separate file that saves and loads timeTick into Core Data.

.m:

```
NSNumber *timetickNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:timeTick];
[newDevice setValue:timetickNumber forKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: The error says that you have the same symbol _timeTick declared in both methods as a global. Don't do that. Show the code of the declarations of _timeTick in easm file.

Comment: @Zaph I have deleted all references to _timeTick. The error still occurs. I am using a int called timeTick. Is this affecting?

Comment: Possibly. Post the code where timeTick is used and we can give you more information.

Comment: @user1118321 I have uploaded my timeTick code. Does this cause the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that every file that `#import`s  the `.h` file now has it's own variable named `timeTick`. What you need to do is make it an external in the header, then define it in the `.m` file. So you're `.h` should look like this:

```
extern int timeTick;
```

Then your `.m` should have this at the top of the file:

```
int timeTick = 0;
```

Then any file which needs access to it would `#import ".h"` and see the definition. Since it's external they won't create their own `timeTick` but will look for one at link time, which they'll find in the `.m` file.